# How many boolean functions of n variables are there?

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics, recurrence

Here is the question I am trying to solve...

---

Show that the number of Boolean functions of n variables is given by the recurrence

T(1) = 4

T(n) = (T(n-1))^2

Solve for T(n).

---

I have been thinking this problem through multiple different ways, but the only thing that makes sense to me is that T(n) would be O(1) since

T(n) = T(n-1) = T(n-2) = T(n-3) = ... = T(n-i) and using i = n-1 would get T(n) = 4

Which would mean that T(n) is O(1) and squaring it would not change anything so

T(n) = (T(n-1))^2 = T(n-1)*T(n-1) ... = 4*4 = 16

Which would mean that T(n) in this case is also O(n). Is this the correct thinking or am I completely off? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The `T` function runs in `O(n)`. It is called exactly `n` times for a given `n`.

Comment: O notation doesn't make sense here, because these are mathematical functions and are not called. `T(n) = T(n-1)` is also obviously wrong - where did you get that?

Comment: A hint: given a function from `i` boolean variables, how would you construct a function from `i + 1` boolean variable?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what your hint is implying to be completely honest. I'm really confused with this question as it has nothing to do with the other questions I'm doing right now.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics and not programming, and thus is more appropriate at math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

There are two independent questions here:

1. Show that the number of boolean functions on n variables obeys the recurrence relation.
2. Solve the recurrence relation.

Let's address each in turn.

### Deriving the Recurrence

Let's start with boolean functions of a single variable. These functions will assign either 0 or 1 to the input 0 and either 0 or 1 to the input 1. This means that there are four possible functions based on those possible outputs. In fact, you can list them all here:

```
f(0) = 0    g(0) = 0   h(0) = 1   i(0) = 1
f(1) = 0    g(1) = 1   h(1) = 0   i(1) = 1
```

Therefore, T(1) = 4.

Now, let's think about how many (n + 1)-variable boolean functions there are. You can think of an (n + 1)-variable boolean function f(b<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>, ..., b<sub>n</sub>, b<sub>n+1</sub>) as being defined in terms of two other n-variable boolean functions g and h:

> g(b<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>, ..., b<sub>n</sub>) = f(b<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>, ..., b<sub>n</sub>, 0)
>
> h(b<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>, ..., b<sub>n</sub>) = f(b<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>, ..., b<sub>n</sub>, 1)

In other words, for any pair of n-variable boolean functions g and h, you can derive a unique (n + 1)-variable boolean function. There are T(n)<sup>2</sup> pairs of n-variable boolean functions, so the total number of (n + 1)-variable boolean functions is T(n)<sup>2</sup>. Thus T(n + 1) = T(n)<sup>2</sup>.

### Solving the Recurrence

Now, we have to figure out how to solve the recurrence

> T(1) = 4
>
> T(n + 1) = T(n)<sup>2</sup>

This is a great place to try unrolling the first few terms:

- T(1) = 4
- T(2) = 16
- T(3) = 256
- T(4) = 65536

These are all powers of two, so it might be a good idea to rewrite them as 2<sup>k</sup> for various choices of k. Doing that yields

- T(1) = 2<sup>2</sup>
- T(2) = 2<sup>4</sup>
- T(3) = 2<sup>8</sup>
- T(4) = 2<sup>16</sup>

From this, it seems like the pattern is that T(n) = 2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup>. We can formalize this by induction:

- T(1) = 4 = 2<sup>2<sup>1</sup></sup>
- T(n + 1) = T(n)<sup>2</sup> = (2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup>)<sup>2</sup> = 2<sup>2 · 2<sup>n</sup></sup> = 2<sup>2<sup>n + 1</sup></sup>

So everything checks out.

There's another way to think about this. Any string of n boolean variables can be thought of as a binary number ranging from 0 to 2<sup>n</sup> - 1. That is, there are 2<sup>n</sup> choices of n boolean variables. For each of those choices, there are two possible outputs from a function, either 0 or 1. Therefore, you can think about the number of n-variable boolean functions as the number of functions from a set of 2<sup>n</sup> elements to a set of two elements. The choice of the output of the function on one input is totally independent of the choice of output of the function on another input, so we're making 2<sup>n</sup> independent decisions of whether to assign 0 or 1. There are 2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup> ways to do this, matching the bound from before.

Hope this helps!